# Trying to multithread a Sieve of Eratosthenes, with each thread taking a range of numbers to sieve

Tags: java, multithreading, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I am unfortunately very very lost on how to start with the multithreading. [Here is my un-threaded sieve code](http://pastebin.com/PQRuq8r4). I assume the threaded code will look very similar. perhaps something like this??? :

```
public class PrimeThread extends Thread {

    private int start, stop;
    ArrayList<Integer> list;

    public PrimeThread(int start, int stop, ArrayList<Integer> list) {
        this.start = start;
        this.stop = stop;
        this.list = list;
    }

    public void run() {
        boolean done = false;
        int currPrime = 0, pos = 2, initVal = 0;

        outerloop:
        for (int i = start; i < stop; i++) { //for every number in the list
            while (list.get(pos) == 0) {
                if (pos == list.size() - 1) {
                    break outerloop;
                }
                pos++;
            }

            currPrime = list.get(pos++); //set the current prime
            initVal = currPrime; //save the initial val of the prime
            done = false;

            while (!done) {
                try {
                    //increment the currPrime by its initial value
                    currPrime += initVal; 
                    //set the number at the new currPrime position to 0
                    list.set(currPrime, 0); 
                } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) { 
                    //if currPrime position > list size, break out of while loop 
                    done = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help explain how to get started please?

Comment: Hey I did something pretty much identical to this with a multithreaded system to generate pictures of prime numbers. If you're interested you can direct message me and I'll share. You can study mine to make adjustments to yours.

Comment: Actually I just got it working. But with some logic errors when I use numbers in the millions. Not sure why. I appreciate your offer though. I may just message you later :)

Comment: Yeah I've spent a lot of attention to detail when it comes to performance and fine tuning everything I can while keeping it as simple as possible. I don't want to rob you of the challenge so do everything you can on your own :) if you're interested I'll put it on my website to grab at your leisure. http://staticadmin.com/GraphicalSieve.zip

Comment: Oh I just realized the one I posted doesn't actually use the Sieve of Eratosthenes but it does use a multithreaded system to calculate the primes.